# How to setup genesis.json for private network for POS conse

Tags: go-ethereum, proof-of-stake, genesis

I want to setup geth based private network using POS consensus, in [Documentation](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/private-network), two sample genesis files are given, one is for default POW and other is for POA, What changes I have to make for POS consensus?

What if for now, I start network with POW and later on switch to POS with hard fork, is it possible?